# Find the equation of the ellipse

Tags: contest-math, conic-sections

An ellipse with centre at $(4,3)$ touches $x$-axis at $(0,0)$. If the slope of the major axis of ellipse is 1, then find the equation of the ellipse?

Comment: How much have you done of this?

Comment: I could find equation of major axis.

Comment: Don't tell *me*, but rather write your work down in the body of your question so that all can see what you've achieved and where you're stuck and can be helped.

Comment: What's happened to the nice solution posted here earlier by @JackDAurizio?

Comment: By "touching" do you mean that the $x$-axis is the tangent? Or do you mean that the ellipse "passes through" that point?

Comment: @hypergeometric I meant tangent.

Comment: And did you mean "touches the $y$-axis" rather than "$x$-axis"? Doesn't look like there's a solution if it's $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ellipse centred at $(4,3)$ with major and minor axes parallel  to the $x-$ and $y-$ axes respectively has the following equation:
$$\frac {(x-4)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-3)^2}{b^2}=1\qquad (a>b>0)\qquad\cdots(1)$$
Applying the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for $\theta=-\pi/4$ and simplifying:
$$\frac{(x+y-7)^2}{2a^2}+\frac{(x-y-1)^2}{2b^2}=1\qquad\cdots(2)$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $x$ and rearranging:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left[\frac{x+y-7}{a^2}-\frac{x-y-1}{b^2}\right]=-\frac{x+y-7}{a^2}-\frac{x-y-1}{b^2}\qquad\cdots (3)$$
Ellipse passes through $(0,0)$. Substituting in $(1)$ and rearranging:
$$ \frac{49}{2a^2}+\frac 1{2b^2}=1\qquad\cdots(4)$$
As $(0,0)$, ellipse touches the $y-$axis, i.e $\frac{dy}{dx}=\infty$. From $(3)$, 
$$ a^2=7b^2\qquad\cdots(5)$$
From $(4),(5)$, 
$$a=2\sqrt{7}, b=2$$
Substituting in $(1)$ gives equation of the tilted ellipse:
$$\frac{(x+y-7)^2}{56}+\frac{(x-y-1)^2}{8}=1\qquad\blacksquare$$
This is the same as 
$$2x^2+2y^2-3xy-7x=0$$

Comment: very nice answer.

Comment: Thank you!  Glad to know you like it.